# hsqldb extremely slow with SELECT * FROM [table]

Tags: java, hsqldb

Im trying to start an embedded version of hsqldb, and it works fine with the tool that are included, they're not slow or anything.

But when i try to use the following code to get 20 rows, it takes up to 10 seconds before all results are printed

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1/woopwoop", "SA", "");

Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ttris_users");

while(rs.next())
{
    output += "<tr>";

    output += "<td>" + rs.getString("id") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + rs.getString("name") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + rs.getString("password") + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + rs.getString("email") + "</td>";
    //name, password, email

    output += "</tr>";
}
```

I initialize the server in a very simple way, and that might be why it runs slow, how can i optimize it?

```
org.hsqldb.server.Server server = new org.hsqldb.server.Server();
server.setDatabaseName(1, "woopwoop");
server.setDatabasePath(1, "C:\\ttris\\db\\");
server.start();
```

In the log that is printed in the console, it shows the query **27** times

[Edit]
heres the first entries in the log

```
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=37523,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @3e0ebb,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 0:Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (woopwoop)
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @3e0ebb,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 0:Connected user 'SA'
[Server@1050e1f]: 0:SELECT * FROM ttris_users
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=37524,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @76fba0,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 1:Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (woopwoop)
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @76fba0,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 1:Connected user 'SA'
[Server@1050e1f]: 1:SELECT * FROM ttris_users
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=37525,localport=9001]) entered
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @1050e1f,5,main]]: handleConnection() exited
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @16dadf9,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 2:Trying to connect user 'SA' to DB (woopwoop)
[Server@1050e1f]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @16dadf9,5,HSQLDB Connections @1050e1f]]: 2:Connected user 'SA'
[Server@1050e1f]: 2:SELECT * FROM ttris_users
```

The issue was located in the servlet that was using the data, and is now resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is off here.  I don't think you're giving us all the code we need to identify the problem.

If your log is showing the query executing 27 times, then this is the problem.  Find out why.  The code you pasted doesn't contain a loop that would cause this.  So I have to assume that the code that's causing this was left out of the sample you gave us.

Put additional entries in the log and trace your program through execution.  Find out where and why it is looping 27 times.  The information you give us shows no indication of this.

Also, you say that you use this code to get 20 tables.  Do you mean 20 records/rows?  I only see a query from one table: `ttris_users`.

Comment: this is the exact reason to why im very confused myself. This is a very simple example im trying to follow from the official documentation. I have corrected the post to indicate that its one table and 20 rows

Comment: Put logging statements before and after the execution, and output the current time in each one so you can see where the delay is.  Trace the code this way and find out what's taking so long.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, the most likely cause of the problem is a loop somewhere outside of the code you provided.  How are you initializing this code?  Where does it sit?  Is it in a thread?  Where do you start the thread?  Somewhere you're doing something 27 times that's causing this code to be executed.  By the way, is it always exactly 27 times?

Comment: It is being run in a servlet, embedded in a Jetty engine, but currently it looks like the servlet is being looped 27 times (which makes absolutely no sense) - and yes, it is always 27 times

Comment: the issue is fixed, and it was (as you suggested) a bug elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

That's very odd about showing the query 27 times; are you sure there's no way this code is being invoked more than once?

Regarding speeding this up: there is going to be a *great deal* of String copying, so much so that it will have a significant performance impact. Consider using a StringBuilder and append() calls:

```
output.append("<td>").append(rs.getString("id")).append("</td>");
```

Comment: This is a great piece of advice.  It's not causing the problem, but it's so much nicer on the memory allocation.